# android: AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

I wrote a custom adapter class extending BaseAdapter implementing Filterable to use with an AutoCompleteTextView. The filtering and selecting is working fine.

The only problem is, if an item from the list is clicked, the AutoCompleteTextView seems to automatically call the adapters `getItem(int position)` method and sets its text to `getItem(position).toString()`.
I dont want this behaviour as Im using custom Objects in the base adapter and this is resulting into strings like `"ClassName [id=xx, variable1=var1]"` put into the TextView.

I tried setting my own OnItemClickListener and OnItemSelectedListener so far, but this seems to only quickly override the above set string instead of directly writing my custom String. How can I disable this default string?

Oh, and overriding the Objects toString() method is not an option in this case.

Any ideas?
regards
danijoo

Comment: It will be more better to understand your issue if you post some relevant code atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this
 autoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                autoCompleteText.setText(str);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is the correct approach. Also possible to get a cursor from the adapterView as shown in http://android.codota.com/scenarios/518919d5da0ad1894c49498c/android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it with the following:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, resource, data);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int index, long arg3)
        {
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter)av.getAdapter();
            Pair customObject = (Pair<Integer, String>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(index);
        }
    });
```

You have to create a custom `getItemAtPosition` method inside your `CustomAdapter`. In this way you do not have to override the `getItem(int position)` requested by the `AutoCompleteTextView` and you can use instead `getItemAtPosition` to return your desired `CustomObject`.